# Which file of android should be run in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am beginner in Android.I have downloaded Android Apps from [link](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-feed-example-using-php-mysql-volley/).  The organization of downloaded file is shown in:

[image]

However, I dont know how I can run it. Which file should be run in Android Studio.

Answer (score 1):

You can import project download from github use Android studio like this :

[image]

[image]

And run it

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your respond. Please download it and check. I did your suggestion. The left bar mentioned noting to show when I select Android.

Comment: @MohammadAliNematollahi I download it and run normal, please check my edit answer

Comment: I have done your guidance. Import->create project from existing source->Next ... Next->Overwrite->Next ... Next                                                                           22.2.1, Android test, ..., r folder are appeared in left side. I will really really appreciate, if you can tell me step by step simply. Thanks.

Comment: @MohammadAliNematollahi delete your current example and try again. As you can see my first image, in the welcome screen of android studio, choose ``Import project(Eclipse ADT, Gradle, etc.)`` -> in the dialog appear, select name of example project ``Feed-Example-...`` -> click OK -> Android studio will auto config and build gradle -> if don't see anything in , please close android stuio and re-open it.

Comment: Because it's project build with gradle, so you can **import** it use Android studio very easy. Don't **create project from existing source**

Comment: I choose Import project(Eclipse ADT, Gradle, etc.)->Select name of project which is android-login-and-registeration-with-php-mysql-> A window is opened and ask me create project from existing source or import project from external model :( several time I close and open and restart it however it does not change

Comment: When I choose import project from external model. It asked me about gradle home

Comment: From your link to Tutorial, i get the project from https://github.com/probelalkhan/Feed-Example-Application-Android-Studio
Please check it.

Comment: if I just push finished bottom without setting it, an alert appear which say gradle location is not specified

Comment: @MohammadAliNematollahi i think you download wrong project. please check it in https://github.com/probelalkhan/Feed-Example-Application-Android-Studio

Comment: I did download it. I have exactly done these steps. An alert is shown mentioned Cannot launch AVD in emulator Output: ERROR x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration! please ensure intel HAXM is properly installed and usable. CPU acceleration statues: HAX kernel module is not installed!

Comment: Ahhh, this is a different problem. Do you have real device. If not, i suggess you use genymotion from https://www.genymotion.com/#!/download instead of default AVD

Comment: You mean "android-login-and-registeration-with-php-mysql" file which I have downloaded, is damaged?

Comment: Because, i didn't use default AVD before, it's bad, so i suggues you use genymotion for test, it'll better. Your downloaded source is ok

Comment: Sorry to take your time. You mean if I download genymotion, I can run "android-login-and-registeration-with-php-mysql" file?

Comment: 1. You can run project with Genymotion better than default AVD of android studio.
2. i'm not sure your downloaded project ``android-login-and-registeration-with-php-mysql`` contain what. So can you post link download in here

Comment: Here is the link https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-feed-example-using-php-mysql-volley/

Comment: Yup, i see, but where you get project ``android-login-and-registeration-with-php-mysql`` , i think you download wrong place, it's here https://github.com/probelalkhan/Feed-Example-Application-Android-Studio ????

Comment: @MohammadAliNematollahi :(( Please make sure : your link post is ``Android Feed Example using PHP, MySQL and Volley`` but why you have project name ``android-login-and-registeration-with-php-mysql``

Comment: Sorry I got it Feed-Example-Application. Now can you help me I have installed genymotion. I dont know how to use it :(

Comment: Here is how to use it, very clear https://www.genymotion.com/#!/developers/user-guide

Answer (score 0):

shift + F10, and if you don't have an emulator it'll ask you to create one.